# Swift, Get action Bar Button Action from Container

Tags: swift

I have ParentViewController.swift and ChildContainer.swift.
In ParentViewController, I have bar button item action like below :

```
@IBAction func onClickBarItemRefresh(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Refresh")
}
```

I want to know, how to call/get this action from ChildContainer?
I can change the title with `parent?.navigationItem.title = "YourName"`, but I cannot find related question about to get the action.

Addition Info:
I have like 4 or 5 container in 1 ParentViewController, so all logic is on their container. So I need call the action on 4 or 5 child container with different login inside the action

Comment: What's the type of ChildContainers? `UIView` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: @MBT it is UIViewController, so the ChildContainers have .swift

Comment: I have deleted the answer as it’s need more clarification. I’m a bit busy now. I will add another answer within next 12 hours. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @MBT ah ok love to wait, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare a callback function in the `ContainerViewController`.

```
var refreshButtonTapped: (() -> Void)?
```

In `ParentViewController` where you initialise `ContainerViewController` give action of the callback function.

In your case create a separate method i.e. `refreshContent()` and call it from `onClickBarItemRefresh()` method and also in `refreshButtonTapped` function where you initialise `ContainerViewController`.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(onClickBarItemRefresh(_:)))
        
        showContainerVC()
    }
    
    @objc func onClickBarItemRefresh(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        refreshContent()
    }
    
    private func refreshContent() {
        print("Refresh Content")
    }
    
    func showContainerVC() {
        let vc = ContainerViewController()
        // call refreshContent() inside the callback function
        vc.refreshButtonTapped = { [weak self] in
            self?.refreshContent()
        }
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.addChild(nav)
        nav.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 320, height: 200)
        self.view.addSubview(nav.view)
        nav.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

In `ContainerViewController` where you want to perform the action of `refreshContent()` just call the callback function `refreshButtonTapped` like below. For example i call it from `viewDidAppear()` method. It will perform the action of refreshing in `ParentViewController`.

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var refreshButtonTapped: (() -> Void)?
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(#function)
        // call this where you want to perform refreshing of ParentViewController
        refreshButtonTapped?()
    }
}
```

Comment: why you add refresh button on customviewcontroller? my refresh button is on parent controller

Comment: now it's work with some modification